# Most of the Virtualization products developed by VMware,Citrix,Microsoft etc are written in which language

Tags: vmware, virtualization, citrix

Wanted to know the programming languages used by many virtualization products.Also would like to know the scripting languages used . May i know the programing language and scripting languages which go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3):

VMware's virtualization products are mostly in C and a bit of x86 assembly, with C++ or other languages for the GUIs. Other languages are used in various other bits, but the above three cover the majority.

Answer (score 1):

An educated guess by the fact that these programs have to access very low level hardware would be they are all written in C and C++.